# Microsoft EDGE - Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl, iis, microsoft-edge

We are getting following error in `Microsoft EDGE` in our Dev environment when we run our `ASP.NET` Application Hosted in `IIS 8` in `Windows 2012 R2` Server.

`Error:
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid.`

Following are more details about implementations and environments. 
Our application runs on 2 different secured ports (`HTTPS`). In `IIS` both apps are hosting as different Web Applications and using same certificate. The certificate is generated using `OpenSSL SHA2 encryption` and it has been added in Secured Certificate Store.

From `Microsoft EDGE when we first load our application, it issues certificate warning message, and we are allowing to proceed. Once page is loaded, on a button click we are calling an API using AJAX call and that is hosted on different port.

In `EDGE` it is not allowing to proceed that API and giving above mentioned error.

In `Chrome and IE 11` also, we are getting same warning message but from there it is allowing to execute next API.

Any help would be appreciated to fix the issue.

Comment: Seeing the same issue in an ASP.net MVC 5 application only in Edge. Having a hard time finding any posts on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your certificate is valid, a possible reason this might happen is if you have a tool running in the background somewhere that hijacks the SSL connections through a proxy, such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Since such a tool is effectively using a man-in-the-middle attack to report the requests, the warnings are "normal". It's pretty easy to forget them running, too.